# MySQL with all and blank counts

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table

Here's a simplified snapshot of [my data on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a52ff0/3). Its basically a 3 column table with employee emails (emp_email), departments (emp_dept) and some text data (emp_assessment_data). The query for department names and headcount is simple:

```
SELECT `emp_dept`,COUNT(*) AS 'DEPT_COUNT' FROM `employee_master` GROUP BY `emp_dept`
```

How to I write a query to add one more column which has a count of only blank emp_assessment_data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `emp_dept`, 
COUNT(*) AS 'DEPT_COUNT', 
SUM(IF(`emp_assessment_data` = '', 1, 0)) as 'BLANK_EMP_ASSESSMENT_COUNT' 
FROM `employee_master` GROUP BY `emp_dept`
```